# Is here a possibility to use yandex tiles with custom TileProvider Android Google Maps v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, yandex-api, yandex-maps

As yandex map [documentation](https://api.yandex.com.tr/maps/doc/theory/concepts/coordinates.xml) says:

```
In contrast to certain other cartographical services, Yandex.Maps uses the elliptical Mercator projection (complying with WGS 84), rather than the spherical projection. This is why a Yandex map will not match up with maps that use the spherical Mercator projection.
```

But Google Map Android v2 seems doesn't have support for other projections except spherical Mercator. Because of this I have huge difference between Yandex Map tiles location and others Tile Providers which use spherical Mercator.

Now I'm getting tiles from static api like this:

```
http://vec04.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&v=2.26.0&x=2392&y=1386&z=12&lang=ru-RU
```

Is here a way to change projection for Google Map Android v2?

Is here other api to get spherical Mercator tiles from yandex?

Comment: Please pay attention to the terms of use for Yandex.Maps API. It's prohibited to use tiles in 3rd-party systems without Yandex API. So, it would be a violation if you use Yandex tiles with google API